# PHP call time pass by reference workaround

Tags: php

To simplify escaping strings using mysql_real_escape_string I was hoping to be able to write a function that would take an arbitrary number of arguments and apply the function to them all.

Something like this:

```
function escape()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $args);
}
```

As you should be able to see, this would rely on the arguments being passed to this function as references.  Given that call time references can't be done in PHP anymore what's the best workaround to this?  As I have a not insignificant number of functions that write specific subsets of info to the database I really need a generic function like the above rather than having calls to `mysql_real_escape_string` everywhere.

My testing has also indicated that arguments passed to `mysql_real_escape_string` are always passed by value.  So even if I could get a reference to `escape()` my hard work is subsequently destroyed.  Is there any way around this?

There must be other people with a similar use case out there but maybe the solution is to just call the function directly.  At least I can wrap `mysql......` in a function with a shorter name to keep the code cleaner.  This may just be a situation where PHP has no equivalent to being able to pass a pointer.

Comment: Since you've tagged this question php5, have you given any thought to moving to PDO?  I know it seems like a headache to make the switch, but the parameterised sql greatly reduces the need for this kind of redundant sanitisation in most cases. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, it's not pretty.

The long answer is:

```
function escape_all(array $args) {
    foreach($args as &$arg) {
        $arg = mysql_real_escape_string($arg);
    }
}

escape_all(array(&$foo, &$bar));
```